# how to prove a language is decidable

Tags: decision-problem

Hopefully this is not a duplicate

How do I prove a Language L={a,b,c} is decidable or not

I read somewhere that if a turing machine accepts a language and halts on every input string then the language is decidable.

Having said that how do i design / prove that a turing machine accepts {a b c}

I am new to concepts of automata and compelexity so please don't kill me if this is too basic for a question

Comment: By definition, a language is decidable if there is a Turing machine that accepts it, that is, halts on all inputs, and answers "Yes" on words in the language, "No" on words not in the language.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus how do i prove the above statement, can you help me with an example on how a turing machine will accept the language, I am too naive and trying to get a grip

Comment: Your textbook can probably help you, as are many online resources. What resources are most helpful for you depends on your level. You can start with http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~cse350/slides/turing1.pdf and http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~cse350/slides/turing2.pdf.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus  Thanks for the links will look into them :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition, a language is decidable if there exists a Turing machine that accepts it, that is, halts on all inputs, and answers "Yes" on words in the language, "No" on words not in the language. Therefore one way of showing that a language is decidable is by describing a Turing machine that accepts it.

There are many offline and online resources on Turing machines. For example, here are some introductory slides on Turing machines: [part 1](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~cse350/slides/turing1.pdf), [part 2](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~cse350/slides/turing2.pdf).